# How to Pick Multiple Video From Gallery in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

EveryOne I want to pick multiple video from gallery and show in my flutter app but I am unable to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker), it has option to pick/upload **multiple files** i.e

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: true);
```

as well as **Multiple files with extension filter** i.e

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
  type: FileType.custom,
  allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'pdf', 'doc'],
);
```

Comment: this isnt from the gallery